# How to work with serialize array database Wordpress to make CRUD operation?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-database

I have data in the metauser table as shown below. As you can see, the data is in the form of a serialized array. How do I push array data? I want to save the post id in the meta bookmark. But if I use `add_user_meta()` instead it creates data in a new row instead of adding data in value (so there will be 2 meta bookmarks in 1 user with different values). If I use `update_user_meta()` it just replaces the old new value, not adding (push) the array data. How do I add new data (array) to the meta value?

[image: table usermeta in wordpress]

Like the example image below, this is the meta of `post_status` and `comment_status` from plugin ulike WordPress. I think when there are new posts or new comments, the value will also increase according to the associated id.

[[image: table ulike_meta from plugin ulike in wordpress2]

please, free to edit this question if there is an incorrect or unsuitable word.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_user_meta` function to get value.

```
$post_status = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'post_status', true );
```

> Now modify `$post_status` array as per your requirement. and update
> after it.

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'post_status', $post_status );
```

Remember WordPress uses `maybe_serialize` and `maybe_unserialize` to save and get value from meta tables.

Answer (score 0):

To store an array as a user meta in the Wordpress database you can use the PHP `serialize()` function. In this example an array will be stored for the current user (as in your screenshot).

```
$bookmark = array(
    0 => 3058,
);
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_bookmark_article', serialize($bookmark) );
```

To modify a serialized array you can use the PHP `unserialize()` function. In this example, the user meta `_bookmark_article` will be retrieved, modified and updated:

```
// retrieves the value of the user meta "_bookmark_article"
$bookmark_article = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_bookmark_article', true );
// convert value to array
$bookmark_article = unserialize( $bookmark_article );

// adds a value to the array
$bookmark_article_updated = $bookmark_article_array[] = 3445;
// updates an array value based on the key
$bookmark_article_updated = $bookmark_article_array[0] += 50;

// updates the value of the user meta "_bookmark_article"
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_bookmark_article', serialize($bookmark_article_updated) );
```

Comment: Better to use WP `maybe_serialize()`

Comment: @Bhautik Sure. But if you know that that value is an array you can use the PHP `serialize()` function. The `maybe_serialize()` function will return the same in case it is an array or object.